# Dynamic variables on method parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(el) {
  $(this).click(function(el) {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      clickedItems += 100;
      $('#jqmeter-container').jQMeter({raised: clickedItems})
    } else {
      clickedItems -= 100;
    }
  })
});

$('#jqmeter-container').jQMeter({
  goal:'$600',
  raised: '$' + clickedItems,
  meterOrientation:'horizontal',
  width:'100%',
  height:'50px'
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>
```

This is a progress bar that gets updated everytime I check / uncheck a checkbox. The issue is, the `raised` parameter inside the `jQmeter` function is not updating when I check / uncheck a checkbox.

How can I pass it a dynamic value so the progress bar will listen to changes on click?

Comment: Check the documentation to see whether it allows you to pass a function or selector string. If so, that's how you do it.

Comment: I haven't found anything in the docs. Is there some way to pass a selector string or function by myself?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function...` instead of the `each` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin doesn't maintain any state, you can't just fill in a specific parameter and have it update the meter. Just call it each time with all the parameters, and the updated `clickedItems` value.

```js
var clickedItems = 0;
var jqmeter_params = {
  goal: '$600',
  raised: '$' + clickedItems,
  meterOrientation: 'horizontal',
  width: '100%',
  height: '50px'
};

$('#jqmeter-container').jQMeter(jqmeter_params);

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(el) {
  $(this).click(function(el) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      clickedItems += 100;
    } else {
      clickedItems -= 100;
    }
    jqmeter_params.raised = '$' + clickedItems;
    $('#jqmeter-container').jQMeter(jqmeter_params)
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for assisting. I tried something similar to this, but I keep getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`, which is a line in the plugin file (`r.goal.replace(/\D/g,""))`)

Comment: Fixed it, should be using `jqmeter_params` in both places.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the updating of the progress bar. Its super annoying that it begins from the start all the time, but will look for a solution for that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is meant to be a replacement for a progress bar that updates continuous. It looks like it's supposed to be a one-time display.